# scroll div only if it is not in the window scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have this code:

the side bar div is my question here

i'm scrolling the page down and i want the div to scroll as well but to stop scrolling the moment it's bottom is visibale... then when scrolling up the same thing with the top of the div

i don't even know what to look for to make any thing with it

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                position: relative;
            }

            #header {
                background:red;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                position:fixed;
                top: 0px;
            }

            #sidebar {
                float:left;
                background: blue;
                width:120px;
                min-height:100px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50;
                left:0;
            }

            #footer {
                background:red;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                position:fixed;
                bottom: 0px;
            }

            #content {
                margin: 60px 0px 60px 140px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
            sidebar<br />
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            top<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            text<br />
            bottom<br />
        </div>
        <div id="header">
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [there](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/bMp3w/2/) if that is what you wish to have.

Comment: Great! is it posible to have the side bar to go back up the moment you start scrolling up? instead of when you reach the specific point it stopped scrolling down? do you get me?